# How to reserve qty for magento in cart for a specific time?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, cataloginventory

Let say Product A has 1 qty left in inventory, If a customer add to cart that product, it should be reserved for 10min or specfied, If he clear checkout while that time otherwise it should back into stock.

Comment: No kudos to those who closed this issue because it is INDEED relevant.

Answer (score 1):

So a bit too broad to answer this with working code but I googled and plumrocket already has a module that does this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cart-reservation-by-plumrocket-inc.html

Never used it myself but it seems to reserve stock for an X number of minutes

Comment: Yes i have seen this but i want to develop something from scratch, I need a logic on this thing.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more in your question about what you have tried so far etc. The functionality you're requesting is too broad to completely explain in an answer

Comment: Basically i want if someone buy product first, he has to checkout in X min other wise product qty will restock and during X min that product qty will be reserved for that customer only.